# Unity 3D - UI renders after minimap (a camera's viewport)

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, render, viewport

How can I make my UI render after my second camera's viewport?(I want UI elements behind the minimap)
I set my main camera's depth to 1 and my minimap camera's depth to 2, but it didn't work.
I couldn't find out how to do this, so I set my minimap frame image's center transparent, so I can see the minimap behind it. (so this is fixed, because usually the frames are in front of the framed thing)

But I've got a new problem, which can't be fixed by transparency :([image: Minimap]

As you can see the health bars, which are instantiated UI elements for the units, are in front of the viewport. Other UI elements are in front of the health bars, like the minimap frame (because I set them to be the first elements in the hierarchy) but the viewport renders before UI so the health bar is in front of it.

How can I fix this? Thank you for your further help :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Or how can I make a minimap in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the minimap to a texture (a RenderTexture). Then in your UI add a Raw Image object. Set the Raw Image to show your minimap RenderTexture.

You now have full control of what is displayed in front of what in your GUI view.